# Apps Script "OR" logical operator

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, or-operator

Our "Current Tutors" sheet has a list of tutor names in column N (shown as row [13] in the code). Column A is the # of students they have (row [0]) in the code.

Basically, we want to filter our Google Form choices so that only tutors with values of 0 or 1 in column A appear. Unfortunately, it looks like the "|" does not do the logical operation of 0 OR 1. It just returns tutor names who have 0 students.

We are not savvy with coding, so any down-to-earth explanation is appreciated!

```
var approvedtutors = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="0"|"1").map(row => row [13])
```

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWlcM.png)

Comment: tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="0" || row[0] ==  "1").map(row => row [13])

Comment: It might allso be `tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0] == 0 || row[0] == 1).map(row => row [13])`

Comment: how about tutorNames.filter(row=>parseInt(row[0] < 2)).map(row => row [13])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Google Apps Script / JavaScript the OR operator is `||` not `|`.

Change

```
var approvedtutors = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]=="0"|"1").map(row => row [13])
```

by

```
var approvedtutors = tutorNames.filter(row=>row[0]== "0" || row[0] == "1").map(row => row [13])
```

Reference

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR